# Is it correct to say "Climb the other way!" or "Climb the other way round!" or "Go to the other side and climb!"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

[image]

There is a climbing structure for children to play as shown in the picture. There are 2 flights of stairs and children can climb either side.

The boy is standing on one side and you want him to go to the other side and climb.

Is it correct to say "**Climb the other way!**" or "**Climb the other way round!**" or "**Go to the other side and climb!**" or "**Climb from the other side!**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the comments are grammatically correct, however they are not equally effective in communicating what you want the child to do.

> Climb the other way!

This comment is the least helpful, because **way** can also mean **method**: there are many possible methods of climbing the frame- though most of them are rather more adventurous than climbing the ladders.

> Climb the other way round!

This could be taken to mean climbing the same ladder, but facing away from the ladder rather than toward it.

> Go to the other side and climb!

This is clear, but I don't like the second imperative (climb)... it sounds like you are forcing the child to climb. "to climb" would be less forceful.

> Climb from the other side!

I think that this sentence is the clearest.

Comment: Or something like "Use the other ladder!"